# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.xxx is not a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React.js for a project and I'm getting some troubles. Here is my problem:

I have this component which is for creating a new recipe:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import { createRecipe } from '../actions/index';

class NewRecipe extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        router:PropTypes.object
    };

    onSubmit(props){
            this.props.createRecipe(props).then(() => {
            this.context.router.push('/yourRecipes');
        });
    }

    render(){
        const name = this.props.fields.name;
        const description = this.props.fields.description;
        const handleSubmit = this.props.handleSubmit;
        return(
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                <h3>New recipe</h3>
                <div>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" {...name} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" {...description} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-primary-spacing">Submit</button>
                <Link to="/yourRecipes" className="btn btn-danger btn-primary-spacing">Cancel</Link>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'NewRecipeForm',
    fields: ['name','description']
}, null, { createRecipe })(NewRecipe);
```

**createRecipe** action creator looks like this inside index.js file:

```
export function createRecipe(props){
  const request = axios.post('http://localhost:3001/recipes/new', props);
    return {
        type: CREATE_RECIPE,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

Everytime I try to click the submit button of the form I get this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.createRecipe is not a function
```

Comment: Can we see how you use `connect`?

Comment: did you mean to use the imported `createRecipe` in your onSubmit function?

Comment: @Surender   yes, when I click the submit the action creator isn't triggered and I get that error

Comment: @splunk you'll need to use it as  'createRecipe' and not as 'this.props.createRecipe'

Answer (score 1):

The error is because there is not such function defined in this react class and you are trying to access it using `this.props.createRecipe`.
One way is you would directly call as `createRecipe()` as you have the import.
One more way is you use connect from react-redux and connect this class with the state and dispatch props and then you can use `this.props.createRecipe()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux-form 6.x.x then you need to make use of connect

```
NewRecipe = reduxForm({
    form: 'NewRecipeForm',
    fields: ['name','description']
}, null)(NewRecipe);

export default(null, createRecipe)(NewRecipe);
```